# A class that inherits from contentView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a class that inherits contentView.
A class called MeasureCompCommon.

I coded the part to be used in common in this class.

Now, each class wants to inherit and use this MeasureCompCommon class.
Inherited from a class called MeasureMainView.

Several errors occur.

############## Error ##############

Compiler Error CS0579

Duplicate 'attribute' attribute

It is not possible to specify the same attribute more than once unless the attribute specifies AllowMultiple=true in its AttributeUsage.

Compiler Error CS0111
Type 'class' already defines a member called 'member' with the same parameter types

CS0111 occurs if a class contains two member declarations with the same name and parameter types. For more

```
namespace POP.Component
{
    public partial class MeasureCompCommon : ContentView
    {
        public MeasureCompCommon()
        {
            Initialized();
        }

        private void Initialized()
        {
            if (this.Parent is StackLayout)
            {
                StackLayout sl = this.Parent as StackLayout;
                int count = sl.Children.Count;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    if (sl.Children[i] != this)
                        sl.Children.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


namespace POP.Component
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MeasureMainView : MeasureCompCommon
    {
        DisplayInfo m_MainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;

        public MeasureMainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitButton();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Attributes are limited to being applied only once to a single field/property/etc. All subclasses are limited in the same way, and should you require multiple instances of the same attribute, you need to explicitly set AllowMultiple to true. So you may add the following sentence before each class that needs to inherit the measurecomprom class:

```
[attributeusage (attributetargets. Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
```

On attributes that allow multiple usages, you should also override the TypeId property to ensure that properties such as PropertyDescriptor.Attributes work as expected. The easiest way to do this is to implement that property to return the attribute instance itself:

```
[AttributeUsage(ttributetargets. Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class  MeasureMainView : MeasureCompCommon
{
public override object TypeId
{
    get
    {
        return this;
    }
}
}
```

If you have any follow-up questions, you can comment again.